# Is it possible to draw anyhitng on MPMoviePlayerController

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

IS it possible to add an points on line in MPMovieplayercontroller..
If yes then how..Becoz as it is possible to draw the line on view .then MPMovieplayerconteoler is also an view only..

```
- (void)drawSquiggle:(Squiggle *)squiggle inContext:(CGContextRef)context
{
   // set the drawing color to the squiggle's color
   UIColor *squiggleColor = squiggle.strokeColor; // get squiggle's color
   CGColorRef colorRef = [squiggleColor CGColor]; // get the CGColor
   CGContextSetStrokeColorWithColor(context, colorRef);

   // set the line width to the squiggle's line width
   CGContextSetLineWidth(context, squiggle.lineWidth);

   NSMutableArray *points = [squiggle points]; // get points from squiggle

   // retrieve the NSValue object and store the value in firstPoint
   CGPoint firstPoint; // declare a CGPoint
   [[points objectAtIndex:0] getValue:&firstPoint];

   // move to the point
   CGContextMoveToPoint(context, firstPoint.x, firstPoint.y);

    // draw a line from each point to the next in order
   for (int i = 1; i < [points count]; i++)
   {
      NSValue *value = [points objectAtIndex:i]; // get the next value
      CGPoint point; // declare a new point
      [value getValue:&point]; // store the value in point

      // draw a line to the new point
      CGContextAddLineToPoint(context, point.x, point.y);
   } // end for

   CGContextStrokePath(context);   
} // end method drawSquiggle:inContext:
```

end method touchesBegan:withEvent:

This is the  code which i had used..
mpPlayer is the mpvideoplayer object

but it is not able to draw point on mpvideoplayer..
Is there any way out.Please help me..

Answer (score 0):

There is an example in the IOS SDK that has an overlay view over a playing movie.  That should be a good start.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MoviePlayer_iPhone/Introduction/Intro.html